# Obtain file name from FileReader object

Tags: java, filenames, filereader

Is there a way to obtain the file name (spc.f), given a FileReader object (f1)?

Whats a good coding practice if you want to remember the file name for later use - store it in another string ?

```
 FileReader f1 = new FileReader("spc.f");
 buffread1 = new BufferedReader (f1 );
 String name = f1.getName();   //  <------ Does something like this exist ??
```

Comment: Don't think it can be done..

Comment: You can get file name from `File` object but not from FileReader's object.

Comment: But you already have the file name why do you need it from the filereader? filename is the input which you provided to the FileReader so u can handle it as u need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code and using the java.io.File object you can retrieve the file name

```
File file = new File("spc.f");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
file.getName();
```

Comment: hmm.. Is there some other unintended benefit of using a File object? It seems to make it explicit that we are dealing  with files and not strings.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer. It requires you to keep track of the File object, and is therefore about as useful as keeping track of the filename string itself.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get file name from a reader object.

But you have file name just before.So you can store it for further process.
Something like this

```
 String file_name= "spc.f";
 FileReader f1 = new FileReader(file_name);
 buffread1 = new BufferedReader (f1 );
 String name = file_name;   //
```

Comment: So the answer is still no, since you didn't get the file name from the `FileReader`.

Comment: @GabrielNegut True Gabriel : But he also asked `Whats a good coding practice if you want to remember the file name for later use - store it in another string ?`  Then the answer is yes,from my side :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess storing it as a String OR as a File object and using getName() works.

Comment: @Nik you are welcome.But I don't think,creating a file Object to just get name is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Save `file_name` in separate `String` and retrieve wherever you want.

You cant get the `file_name` from `FileReader` object.